# How to wire up a DataSourceTransactionManager with @Configuration @Beans instead of XML

Tags: spring

Typical XML for hooking up a transaction manager in Spring looks like:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    .... properties go here ....
</bean>
```

How do I accomplish the same thing with code?

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  @Bean
  public DataSource myDataSource() {
       return new DataSource(); /// and set properties, etc.
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceTransactionManager txManager() {
       --> What goes here? <--
  }
}
```

Specifically, how do I get txManager wired up to the myDataSource singleton via code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `DataSourceTransactionManager` has a constructor that takes `DataSource`, you can do the following (otherwise you would need to call `setDataSource()`):

```
@Bean   
public DataSourceTransactionManager txManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(myDataSource());
}
```

**See also:**

- [3.11.4.2 Injecting dependencies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-injecting-dependencies)

Comment: And this ensures that the same singleton is used here as is injected into my @Repository classes?

Comment: What about cases where you have multiple DataSources annotated with @Profile ?

Answer (score 7):

You can also use multiple transactionManager

```
     @Configuration
        public class MyConfig {
          @Bean
          public DataSource myDataSource1() {
               return new DataSource(); /// and set properties, etc.
          }

          @Bean
          @Qualifier("txManager1")
          public DataSourceTransactionManager txManager1() {
               return new DataSourceTransactionManager(myDataSource1());
          }

          @Bean
          public DataSource myDataSource2() {
               return new DataSource(); /// and set properties, etc.
          }

          @Bean
          @Qualifier("txManager2")
          public DataSourceTransactionManager txManager2() {
             return new DataSourceTransactionManager(myDataSource2());
          }

    }
```

Then when use @Transactional you can define the transactionManager you want :

```
@Transactional("txManager1")
public Object getSomeData(){
    ...
}

@Transactional("txManager2")
public Object getSomeOtherData(){
    ...
}
```